# How long will it take to show the signs of pregnancy after intercourse

Tags: sex, sexuality, conceive-conception, pregnancy-test, obstetrics

How long will it take to show the signs of pregnancy after having intercourse without using any birth control method? Please assume the couple as fertile.

Ex:- Nausea with or without vomiting, Increased urination, Food aversions or cravings, Fatigue

Thanks

Comment: Outside of what has already said, I only know of one other way which my wife and I witnessed.
When one is pregnant and before the missed period there is hormonal changes in effect. Although humans are not able to pick up on these changes(scents), animals do.
When my wife was 2 weeks in we observed our dog take notice of the different scent and that he was put off for a period of time.

Comment: @user68386, Thanks for letting us know, I have never heard something like that before. What's the breed of your dog? How long did he keep put off himself? Did he hate your wife during the period or loved more?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming pregnancy takes place, the only reliable sign that a woman is pregnant is cessation of her menstrual period. If she's late, urine tests are a reliable way to confirm pregnancy, especially if the woman has irregular periods.

Up to 50% of women will not experience nausea (the range, depending on the study, is 15-50%); while most will, when they do varies from early in the pregnancy (as early as 2 weeks after the first missed period, often peaking by the 9th week) to late (sometimes even into the early part of the second trimester).

Urinary frequency is experienced in only about half of women in the first trimester (range 25-60%); Fatigue is subjective and depends on self-reporting; many women do not report fatigue in the first trimester, whereas nearly 100% do in the third trimester.

<sub>[Epidemiology of Nausea and Vomiting of Pregnancy: Prevalence, Severity, Determinants, and the Importance of Race/Ethnicity](http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/708509)</sub>
<sub>[Prevalence of lower urinary tract symptoms during pregnancy in Taiwan](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15818433)</sub>
<sub>[Dewhurst's Textbook of Obstetrics and Gynaecology](https://books.google.com/books?id=N2vXGuG9AZ0C&pg=PA509&lpg=PA509&dq=epidemiology+of+frequency+of+micturition+in+pregnancy&source=bl&ots=zNbNRNQbCi&sig=af86LwhcBh_vzIhMoARba53fFJw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n95UVbjBBYqQsQT8kYHoDQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=epidemiology%20of%20frequency%20of%20micturition%20in%20pregnancy&f=false)</sub>

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by reliable sign. Cessation of the menstrual period does not mean you are pregnant.

Comment: @StrongBad - The question assumed conception has already taken place. In that case, it *is* a reliable sign. But I will edit that in.

Comment: There is another indirect early sign of pregnancy which can be appeared before cessation of period - **basal temperature changes**. The thing is – your blood circulation changes in order to consider the new life in you. Your basal temperature may raise and you may feel hotter than before. Most probably you won’t notice if you have things to do. [10 first signs of pregnancy](http://motherhow.com/first-signs-of-pregnancy-early-pregnancy-symptoms/)

Comment: does fertility always lead to conception?

Comment: @Ooker - Of course not.

Comment: As mentioned by @StrongBad The first statement in this answer is a little odd. Since you're assuming conception occurred, reliability has no meaning. It also isn't the question. A missed period is useful for suggesting further testing, sure, but it is not reliable. "The only reliable sign(s) of pregnancy" are visualization of a gestational sac (on ultrasound) or hearing fetal heart tones. A positive beta-hCG is a good screening test, with a relatively high PPV, sensitivity and specificity,  but again, that isn't the question.